# Cube Map is not showing a texture (OpenGL ES)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0, skybox

I am trying to make a skimp with cube mapping. And I have the cube "painted" already, but there is no texture. I don't know if the problem is, when I am loading my texture, like it is not loading any information. 
Or because it has no Texture Coords... But in tutorials and explanations I found about Cube Mapping, they don't need any Texture Coords.

[image]

As you see, it is painting the cube, but everything is black.

```
#define SIZE 1.0

GLfloat VERTICES[] = {
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,

    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,

    SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,

    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,

    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,

    -SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE
};

@interface CubeMap (){
    GLuint textureId;
    NSString *face[6];
    ObjLoader *objLoader;

    GLuint skyboxVAO, skyboxVBO;

    Shader *shader;
    GLuint program;

    //Unifroms
    GLuint u_modelViewProjectionMatrix;
    GLuint u_texture;
}

@property GLfloat* VertexData;
@property uint ByteSize;


@end

@implementation CubeMap

-   (void)initCubeMape{

    shader = [[Shader alloc] init];
    program = [shader standartProgramaVertPath:@"cubemap" VertType:@"vert" FragPath:@"cubemap" FragType:@"frag"];

    //Texture Locations
    face[0] = @"back";
    face[1] = @"back";
    face[2] = @"back";
    face[3] = @"back";
    face[4] = @"back";
    face[5] = @"back";

    //Uniforms
    glUseProgram(program);
    u_modelViewProjectionMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
    u_texture = glGetUniformLocation(program, "cubeMap");

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureId);

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"back" ofType:@"jpg"];
        NSData *texData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:texData];
        if (image == nil){
            NSLog(@"Image could not been load");
        }


        size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
        size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
        //    NSLog(@"texture image w,h: %zu, %zu", width, height);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
        CGContextRef context0 = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        CGContextClearRect( context0, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
        CGContextTranslateCTM( context0, 0, height - height );
        CGContextDrawImage( context0, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage );

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)width, (int)height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);



        CGContextRelease(context0);
        free(imageData);
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);



    /*********************************
     ***********Buffering*************/

    // Setup skybox VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &skyboxVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &skyboxVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, skyboxVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VERTICES), &VERTICES, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);


}

-   (void)update{

}

-   (void)render{
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
    glUseProgram(program);

    //bind Texture
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureId);
    glUniform1i(u_texture, 0);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelViewProjectionMatrix, 1, 0, _modelViewProj.m);


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

}

@end
```

Just for testing, all faces are loading the same image.

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 position;

varying highp vec3 vTexCoord;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    vTexCoord = position.xyz;
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform samplerCube cubeMap;

varying highp vec3 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    lowp vec4 texCol = textureCube(cubeMap, vTexCoord);

    lowp vec4 color = vec4(vTexCoord, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = texCol;
}
```

This is how it looks like, if I am changing gl_FragColor to color!

[image]

Comment: What's the size of the image? One thing to watch out for is that the images for cube maps need to be square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never load any data into the cubemap. Where you make the `glTexImage2D()` call:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)width, (int)height, 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

The target `GL_TEXTURE_2D` specifies that you want to load data into a regular 2D texture, which is not the texture type you are using.

To load data into a cube map, you have to use the cube faces as targets:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)width, (int)height, 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

The enums for the cube faces have contiguous values, so it is guaranteed that you get the 6 enum values for the faces if you add an index to the first one.